# Trying to add one to array of integers and return array

Tags: java, integer

Given an array of integers eg. [1,2,3]. I'm trying to return an array with the integers plus one. So return [1,2,4]
Getting unexpected output in the case of [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0], should be [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,1]

```
public static int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
        
    int results = 0;
    for (int i =0; i<digits.length; i++) {
        results *=10;
        results += digits[i];
    }
    results +=1;
    String resultsLength = Integer.toString(results);
    
    int newDigits[] = new int[resultsLength.length()];

    for (int i =0; i<resultsLength.length(); i++) {

        newDigits[i] = resultsLength.charAt(i) - '0';
    }

    return newDigits;
}
```

Comment: Examples in questions of this type should include input (✔), expected output (✔), and actual output (✗). There is a lot more to your code than the example indicates.  I think the description of the problem needs improvement.  Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and some of the linked pages

Comment: If all you want to do is increment the last element of an array, `if (digits.length > 0) {  digits[digits.length - 1] += 1; }`

Comment: I suspect that input of `[9, 9]` should return `[1, 0, 0]`. Is that correct?

Comment: @Bohemian yes that's correct.

Comment: You really need to edit your question and explain what you want.  I thought @OldDogProgrammer had the right answer (although much simpler than your attempt).  You're input and expected output don't help add all.

Comment: A number is represented as an `int` array, with each element in the array representing one digit of the number. Code the method to increment the represented number by 1. `public static int[] plusOne (int[] digits)`. Parameter `digits` represents the number. The method returns the result of incrementing the number represented by `digits`.  There still remains a question: Is the method allowed to modify elements of `digits`? Or must they be unaltered?

Comment: @Old you *must* return a new array for the cases of all-9's input, so might as well do it always. Whether you mutate the input of not is a coding discipline thing, but mutating input is generally to be avoided.

Comment: I agree with the comment from @Bohemian. That's why I'm suspicious of answers that modify the `digits` argument. If the process modifies elements of `digits`, and then discovers, each element contained `9`, it might *return* the correct result, but could leave the array in the calling program with element values that are neither correct "before" nor "after".

Answer (score 2):

For the approach you have used, using `BigInteger` like @Reilas's answer would work.

But a more simpler approach to the problem would be

- determine if the input number plus one will result in increased number of digits in output
- declare the output array of the size accordingly
- in case of `hasCarry=true`, set `output[0]=1` and return the output (applies when input is 9, 99, etc.)
- otherwise assign the input array to the output. Increment the `output[i]` by 1 when the `input[i]<9` and assign `output[i]=0` for `input[i]==9`

```
public int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
    boolean hasCarry = true;
    for (int digit: digits)
        if (digit != 9) {
            hasCarry = false;
            break;
        }

    int[] output = hasCarry ? new int[digits.length + 1] : new int[digits.length];

    if (hasCarry) {
        output[0] = 1;
    } else {
        output = digits;
        for (int i = output.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (digits[i] < 9) {
                output[i]++;
                return output;
            }
            output[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: See the comment on the question by Bohemian, and my reply in which I said I agree.

Comment: I agree as well, updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is [over-flowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Use the [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) class.

```java
import static java.math.BigInteger.*;
```

```java
int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
    BigInteger results = ZERO;
    for (int d : digits) {
        results = results.multiply(TEN);
        results = results.add(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(d)));
    }
    results = results.add(ONE);
    String resultsLength = results.toString();

    int newDigits[] = new int[resultsLength.length()];

    for (int i =0; i<resultsLength.length(); i++) {

        newDigits[i] = resultsLength.charAt(i) - '0';
    }

    return newDigits;
}
```

Or, use a *[stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html)*.

```java
int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
    return
        IntStream.of(digits)
                 .mapToObj(x -> new BigInteger(String.valueOf(x)))
                 .reduce(ZERO, (a, b) -> a.multiply(TEN).add(b))
                 .add(ONE)
                 .toString()
                 .chars()
                 .map(x -> Character.digit(x, 10))
                 .toArray();
}
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 4]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner:

```
int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
    return new BigInteger(Arrays.toString(digits).replaceAll("\\D", ""))
      .add(BigInteger.ONE).toString().chars().map(i -> i - '0').toArray();
}
```